# Wrapping a text in a table's cell in LateX

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a problem with wrapping the text in the table's cell when using  `tabular`. The phrase in the cell goes beyond the text width. I tried to apply `multirow` command but it don't change a thing. Why? Well, I receive an error whenever using `multirow` that a curly bracket (}) is missing. I've looked it over and over again and can't see it. Maybe someone could just test it and offer a free of error lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

 \begin{tabular}{lll}
 \hline

  \textbf{Name \& Author(s)} & \textbf{Label}  & \textbf{Definition}                                                                                      \\ \hline

              Poggi 2001     & Nod             & "a down-up movement of the head"                                                                                       \\

              Allwood 2003   & Nod            & "a forward movement of the head going up and down, which can be multiple"\\
```

This is the output that I get:

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please provide a [compilable document](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good application for the `tabularx` package.

Please do not use `"` for quotation marks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llX@{}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Name \& Author(s)} & \textbf{Label}  & \textbf{Definition}\\
        \midrule
        Poggi 2001 & Nod & ``a down-up movement of the head''\\
        Allwood 2003 & Nod & ``a forward movement of the head going up and down, which can be multiple''\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]